# Modal view is not respecting z-index rules, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used some source code which shows a modal view box on a click event. In the online demo it works great, but on my webpage he box loads slightly distorted, with the modal box sitting behind the site logo and site header text.

The articles that I have come across so far online have told me to try the z-index method, as well as having all elements involved set to relative, but this is not useful as it further distorts the rest of my page elements.

I have replicated the issue in this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a0ht7y51/

Also posting the relevant code here:

HTML:

```
 <div id="header">

                    <img id="headerBackground" src="siteImages/tiltchair.jpg">

                    <img id="Logo" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" align="middle" src="siteImages/final.png" alt="Logo">

                    <img id="Text" align="middle" src="siteImages/TWText.png" alt="Logo">
```

```
              <form class="modal-content animate" action="action_page.php">
                <div class="imgcontainer">
                  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                </div>

                <div class="container">
                  <label><b>Username</b></label>
                  <input type="text" class="input-txt"  placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

                  <label><b>Password</b></label>
                  <input type="password" class="input-txt"  placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

                  <button type="submit">Login</button>
                  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
                </div>


                  <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>

              </form>
```

CSS:

```
.input-txt{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background: $blue;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(250, 250, 250, .4);
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
  @include placeholder(lighten($blue, 10%));
  @include transition(background-color .5s ease-in-out);
   &:focus{
     background-color: darken($blue, 30%);
    }
}



p{

    font-size:16px 
    text-align: left;
}

h1 {

    font-size:16px
}

/* CSS for modal */

/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
width: 33%;
padding: 12px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
display: block;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
    background-color: #1dacf9;
    color: white;
    padding: 1px 2px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 33%;
}

/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    background-color: #f44336;
}

 /* Center the image and position the close button */
.imgcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 24px 0 12px 0;

}

img.avatar {
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
    padding: 6px;
}

span.psw {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
}   

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 10; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    padding-top: 60px;
    height: 100vh;
    border-radius: 20px;
    }

 /* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 66%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
    height: 66vh;
    border-radius: 20px;

}

 /* The Close Button (x) */
.close {
     position: relative;
     margin: 2% auto 95% auto;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

 /* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
     -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
     animation: animatezoom 0.6s
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
    from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
 }

@keyframes animatezoom {
    from {transform: scale(0)} 
    to {transform: scale(1)}
}  

 /* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
     span.psw {
        display: block;
       float: none;
    }
    .cancelbtn {
       width: 100%;
    }
}



#headerBackground {

    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: -10;
}

#TWLogo {

transform: translateZ(1px);
display: block;
margin-top: 5%;
margin: 0 auto;
cursor: pointer;
background-attachment: fixed;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
width:150px;
height:125px;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
background-position:center;
z-index: -1;



}
#Logo:hover { transform: scale(1.1); }

#Text {


    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    width:355px;
    height:125px;
    transform: translateZ(30px);
    background-position:center;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

So my minimal knowledge of CSS is preventing me from seeing what could be an easy fix, can anyone see it?

Comment: move your modal into the body and all should be fixed - in your fiddle I have just closed your header tag before your modal: https://jsfiddle.net/a0ht7y51/1/

Comment: @Pete Thanks for your answer, but that doesn't seem to be working on my web page, it already was at the bottom of the <body> tags, I then moved it into the main container <div>, with the same result

Comment: can you paste your full body into the fiddle

Comment: Thats the fiddle updated hopefully thats enough

Comment: @Pete Would you have any idea what else it could be?